# Integrate yslow with selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, yslow

I have written selenium tests in java and want to integrate yslow with it. But i didn't know how to do it.

Provide me with full guidance in Detail.

Comment: https://intensetesting.wordpress.com/2014/04/08/web-performance-report-using-y-slow-showslow-along-with-selenium-tool/